# Debugging JavaScript VS 2008

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2008

I am debugging 12K lines of JavaScript. Of course it is written by the off shore team. Now, I need to find out which js function is invoked when I interact with the UI. Is there anyway for me to just automatically jump into the function which is being executed?

I cannot really put a break point since I have no idea where to put the break point?

App runs only on IE7!

Comment: Install IE8 and run in IE7 mode. Use the debugger there. Upgrade the app so it runs in any browser since IE7 is going bye bye! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can attach VS 2008 to a scripting host process like Internet Explorer. Notice that "scripting host" is specific to the Windows Scripting platform, which isn't used by other browsers.

Internet Explorer should be configured to "Allow script debugging" so that VS can attach to  iexplorer.exe *and* be able to debug scripts running in it.

Bear in mind that this is an extremely frustrating debugging experience. If you can debug in more modern browsers (including IE9, which has decent developer tools), please do so!

Answer (score 0):

Once you've attached Visual Studio to IE7, you can use the **Break All** option to terminate any running scripts.  If no script is running, it will break the moment a script is executed, such as if you hover over an element with the mouse that has an `onmouseover` listener.

[image]

This might get somewhat cumbersome if you are looking for a specific piece of code.  I don't think there's really a way around this besides just tracing through the code until you find the part that's relevent.

If this is a bug that happens when you click on a button, for example, look at the HTML code for the button.  If it has an `onclick` handler, search for that function and set a breakpoint there, or add the word `debugger;` to the top of the function.  If there is no `onclick` handler, search for the `ID` of the button in your Javascript code and see if any listener is bound to that DOM element.

There's really no reason why 12,000 lines of Javascript code should thwart your efforts to see what's going on.  Find a repro for the issue, and then use Find to locate the relevant code in your Javascript file.  Also, I realize your site might not work in Firefox or Chrome, but it might work in IE8 since it's fairly backwards compatible.  IE8 has a better debugger and also the ability to explore various DOM elements which could come in handle for tracing what code is run where.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The problem is there is no onclick. Everything is generated on the fly and then injected into a DIV.

Comment: I recommend installing the IE Developer Toolbar.  It will allow you to inspect the DOM at runtime.  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359